# mysql convert IPs to unsigned in while loading

Tags: mysql, ip

I have a small txt file with a few IP addresses (without quotes). I want to load them into a mysql table as unsigned integers. How can do that nicely? Is there a way to convert them (inet_aton) on the fly while loading?

Currently, I first create a small table where the IP addresses are loaded as text and then, create another table, insert into that as unsigned-ints (inet_aton).

thanks!

Comment: Did you consider IPv6 format? It's not "just text of digits and dots". Hence, can be converted to ints, very-very big ints

Comment: No. Just IPv4 addresses.

Comment: IPv4 addresses come in several forms, where `1`, `1.1`, `1.1.1` and `1.1.1.1` are all valid. Ignoring IPv6 is also a good way of creating enormous amounts of technical debt. As a note, if you're not too married to MySQL, it's worth noting that Postgres [has native IP types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-net-types.html) if this is core to what you're doing.